# replace value in same location

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a=[2,3,1,5,6,7] 
b=[0,0,2,4,6,0]
```

Can anyone tell me how I can I delete  [1,5,6] in the array a and replace with b value [2,4,6]?

Comment: Is the point that you are only replacing where the value in b is nonzero?

Comment: try to give a detailed information about your question. Add your code , what issue your facing? , where your blocking? , what you tried so far? like the way you have to ask your question. Please [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) , and be sure to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [list slicing](https://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-slice-listsarrays-and-tuples-in-python/):

Logic: Replace all non-zero values from b to a.

```
In [2082]: a=[2,3,1,5,6,7]

In [2083]: b=[0,0,2,4,6,0]

In [2104]: for c,i in enumerate(b):
      ...:     if i != 0:
      ...:         a[c] = i
      ...:         

In [2105]: a
Out[2105]: [2, 3, 2, 4, 6, 7]
```

Comment: a[2:5] = b[2:5] actually the array size is not this much.I want logic but I did with help of loop I am not able to solve the problem

Comment: @MissPriyaKumari I've updated a logic in the answer. It will replace all elements of `a` with `b` where elements of `b` is non-zero. Please check.

Comment: thanks, this work for me

Comment: can i do for this 2d array

Comment: for y, row in enumerate(e):
        for x, element in enumerate(row):
                #if y!=0
                if y != 0 and x!= 0:
                        b[y,x]=y,x                          i know this not correct logic tell me how to do ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **slicing** like this:

```
a = [2,3,1,5,6,7]
b = [0,0,2,4,6,0]
a[2:5] = b[2:5]
print(a)

>>> [2, 3, 2, 4, 6, 7]
```